# Macbook Pro SSD Upgrade

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, hardware, ssd, upgrade

I have a MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014) (11,3) and I'm looking to change it's drive.

I've found 2 models that I think fits my model.

1. [OWC 480GB Aura Pro X SSD For Mac Pro (Late 2013) with Envoy Pro Enclosure](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B076Y57JHN)
2. [Transcend 480GB JetDrive 820 PCIe Gen3 x2 Solid State Drive](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B075HBJPYF)

Does anyone know if these 2 would work with my computer?  Are there any other SSDs that would work with this model MacBook Pro?

Comment: Looking at the product descriptions, one only lists the 2013 Mac Pro (OWC) and the other (Transcend) gives you a range of models  it's compatible with.  Go with the one that *specifically* states it's compatible.

Answer (score 1):

You should be fine with many SSD models on the market, among these you can find the ?amsung EVO 850 series, just as an example. If you replace the original HDD for an SSD, however, be aware that you will need to enable TRIM manually on your new SSD. Please check [this page on trimforce](https://randomnerds.com/execute-sudo-trimforce-enable-to-keep-your-ssd-healthy/).